Feature selection for Cox Model with low event number
I am interested in wether a set of 30 variables can predict OS in cancer. I have reduced my features to 15 after checking for multicollinearity. The problem is, I only have around 70 events in my data set (among 182 individuals), which I believe makes it difficult for me to include all these variables in a final model.
I am not sure what (if anything) can be done to approach this question? I keep reading suggestions about step-wise selection, LASSO and PCA however, I am not sure which option (if any) are the best approach. Can anyone suggest a way forward?
Thanks

This thread may be useful.   Stepwise is terrible.

Please edit the question to say more about why you need to do variable selection. For example, if your interest is in prediction, you can keep information from all features by using ridge regression. That avoids overfitting by penalizing the regression coefficients.
